# Multiple cursors in Lubuntu - Shift + Alt + arrow (up/down)

Tags: ubuntu, cursor, sublimetext2

The multicursor feature used to work very well for me when using [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu). I recently installed [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) and very disappointedly I realized that the feature does not work here.

In a multi line piece of text/code I used to go to some point and then press the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + arrow (up/down). This created new cursors in the direction of the arrow.

It seems gone, and maybe it does not work in [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE)? Is there a way to port the functionality in Lubuntu if that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this could be happening. The most likely is you have a system shortcut that is overriding the Sublime Text one. Go to the Keyboard Shortcuts section in your System Settings app and make sure none of them use this key combination.

The key combo could also have been overwritten in Sublime itself by a plugin. To see what (if any) action is assigned to this key combo, open Sublime's console (**`View → Show Console`**) and run the following command:

```py
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Now, with the console still open, click in the text of the open file and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> - you should see

```
command: select_lines {"forward": true}
```

if the command was working properly. If nothing shows up, the issue is most likely with a system override as discussed above. If something else shows up, it's probably from a plugin.

To find out what plugin it might be, install the [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts) plugin and run `FindKeyConflicts: (Direct) Conflicts to Buffer` from the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>). Search through the resulting file to see where else this particular key combination is defined.

Comment: Thanks so much ^_^
I did as suggested and the Sublime terminal was not showing anything so i went to the openbox config file (/home/__user__/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml) and removed these lines:
    <keybind key="S-A-Up">
      <action name="SendToDesktop">
        <to>up</to>
        <wrap>no</wrap>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="S-A-Down">
      <action name="SendToDesktop">
        <to>down</to>
        <wrap>no</wrap>
      </action>
    </keybind>
Then i reloaded openbox via ~$ openbox --reconfigure and the keybinding worked.

Comment: @Nicola glad to hear it. I run Linux in a virtual machine (VMWare Fusion on OS X), and I've had issues with VM keybindings overriding those from Sublime, which is why I suggested it. Cheers!

Comment: Re *"Go to the Keyboard Shortcuts section in your System Settings app"*: I couldn't locate that for Lubuntu 18.04. Can you update your answer so it ***also*** covers later versions of Lubuntu? Alternatively, if it does exist, can you add the path/actions to get to it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't use Lubuntu, so I'm afraid I can't update the answer for that particular distribution. The answer still stands as-is in Ubuntu 21ish (I don't have a specific release because I update as updates are published. Originally it was 20.04, I think.). The System Settings app is called *Settings* now, I don't know if it's a change, but there is still a *Keyboard Shortcuts* section in the main menu.